# Can I downgrade from original MS Windows 10 that comes preinstalled with my laptop to Windows 7 without losing the license?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I have a laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10. I usually use Ubuntu but I use Windows at times. The problem with Windows is that now it updates over metered Wi-Fi connections as well which makes it impossible to connect to the internet without losing precious data. This is very much annoying but as an old user of Windows 7, which I loved, I would really love to install Windows 7. Is there any way for me to so that without losing the license I have currently?

Comment: At this point in time when Windows 7 has only months of support left, installing it is a very bad idea. It doesn't matter how much you love it or any other reasons. Any OS not patched with security updates is dangerous for the user and everyone else if used in the internet. Plus, if you have no valid Win7 license now you'll never get one because Microsoft aren't selling them since a long time ago. If you don't what Windows 10 then be smart and use Linux.

Comment: Your new licence of Windows 10 is tied to the hardware so you have a perpetual Windows 10 licence. If you do not currently have a Windows 7 licence you will need to buy one. Windows 10 does not come with any downgrade rights.

Comment: He says it came pre-installed with Windows 10, so he would already have an OEM license in that case and wouldn't need to spend money on another one.

Comment: Good luck finding drivers for that hardware and Windows 7.

Comment: You can configure your system, as being connected to a metered connection, and Windows won't attept to download updates.  In other words, it isn't necssary to downgrade to Windows 7, to achieve that goal

Comment: Try some of the work-arounds to block updates, e.g. https://zillowtech.com/disable-automatic-updates-windows-10-home.html . Or stick with *just* Ubuntu... many Windows progams run in wine (or in WinPE, such as Macrium Reflect, which creates its own WinPE disk).

Answer (score 2):

You say windows 10 updates over a metered connection.

Did you go here and turn it off?
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the question: "Can I downgrade from original MS Windows 10 that comes preinstalled with my laptop to Windows 7 without losing the license?"

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný  The OP clearly states this as the **primary** reason he doesn't want windows 10.  This solves that problem and then he does need a windows 7 license.  So it an alternative answer.

Comment: Okey, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You will not lose the OEM Windows 10 license, as it is tied to the machine itself via the hardware. Windows 10 does not use keys in the same way that Win7 did, so there's no key to export, you simply have to reinstall Windows 10 <strike>using the OEM media</strike>.

Comment: "...you simply have to reinstall Windows 10 using the OEM media." He doesn't need to use OEM media to activate Windows 10. Windows 10 doesn't care about OEM media. He should keep it simple and do a clean install using a bootable USB drive made directly from the Microsoft website. Microsoft's activation servers will recognize the hardware (if 10 activated online before) and will immediately reactivate it as soon as it reconnects to the internet post-reinstall. He also won't need to do major updates as Windows would be up to date right off the bat, unlike with outdated OEM media.

Comment: Thanks, @wrecclesham. I was unaware of that.